# Auto reloading no longer working after Django 1.11 to 3.2 upgrade

Tags: python, django

After upgrading an old inherited codebase from Django 1.11 to 3.2.13, I've found that Django no longer automatically reloads the server whenever a file change occurs. I've looked at the logger and it does say the the reloader is watching for file changes. After performing one change in the codebase and hitting save, the logger does say that it has detected a file change; however, nothing actually happens and the changes aren't reflected anywhere until you manually restart the server.

If I make any further changes, there are no further logger messages displayed about file changes. I've also noticed that any version of Django before 2.2 seems to work in terms of reloading properly. It was only after upgrading to 2.2 and 3.2 that I noticed any issues.

Here is a snippet from the logs.

```
Staring threads ['manage.py', 'runserver']
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 12, 2022 - 20:07:04
Django version 3.2.13, using settings 'api.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[none] 2022-05-12 20:07:21,827 django.utils.autoreload INFO     /api/settings.py changed, reloading.
```

Has anyone else run into this issue before?

For reference, I'm currently testing on the following environment:

- MacOS Monterey (12.3.1, M1)
- Python 3.9.12 (have also tested 3.7 and 3.8)

Comment: Does a new Django project work fine in the same environment?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just booted up a new quick start project and it seems to be reloading on new changes as expected.